# How to delete specific part of a mesh that follows a Bezier curve, through geometry nodes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, procedural

I am working on meshes which is created based on idea of tessellations, I want mesh to follow a curve (say, Bezier) using geometry nodes, which I am able to do to some extent, but the issue is, once the mesh follows the curve, and now if I go to Edit mode for Bezier curve and draw a curve with Pen tool (where curve gets separated on 'Layout editor', with same name on 'outliner Panel'), the mesh do follows the new curve, but it gets stretched (or scaled) between last part of original curve and first part of second curve,

This is repeated every time I create a curve in edit mode, which is undesirable and I would like to delete this 'stretched / scaled part' of mesh geometry. How do I do that?

[image: Mesh stretching which is to be deleted]

Here is the geometry node set up that helped me bend the mesh along the curve

[image]

It may also be noted that, in the above geometry nodes set up, if I un-tick 'All Curves' under Sample Curve node, the mesh only follows (bends along) initial Bezier curve (and does not follow curve created after changes through edit mode)

*Here is the sample code:*

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Try to capture the spline Index and use it in the sample curve node (uncheck All Curves for the index socket to appear)

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: Okay, I used 'Index' node and attached to 'Curve index' input of 'Sample Curve' node, but it did not work (mesh got flattened on X-Y plane), I disconnected 'Index' and manually changed index value between 0 and 1 and mesh shifted from curve 1 to curve 2, I need to delete the geometry between the two curves.

Comment: @RickT  I have added an example .blend file for reference.